# How to properly look for an info about auditd being turned off from init?

Tags: log-files, fedora, auditd

I have a mystery on my hands. One day `/etc/rc5.d/S11auditd` became `/etc/rc5.d/K88auditd` and no one takes responsibility for it. It looks like it just happened by itself, which is hardly plausible and requires a little investigation.

Assuming default Fedora 12 installation, what are the ways of tracing actions that led to an `auditd` being removed initialization sequence? So far I checked:

`/var/log/messages` shows that one time the demon was properly shut down on reboot and never loaded again.

`/var/log/audit/audit.log` via `ausearch` shows basically the same thing.

`chkconfig | grep audit` shows that it is currently shut off, but only on 5th run level.

I even tried `.bash_history` with no luck.

`last` also shows that no one used `ssh` to login remotely.

So, what did i missed? Where to look for more info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had the same problem and have a possible explanation.

In my case, I suspect that it was caused by the `readahead` package which temporarily disables `auditd` during boot by changing the `rc.d` links (see `/etc/init/readahead-disable-services.conf`).  It is supposed to change them back at the end of the boot sequence, but if you interrupt that (e.g. CtrlAltDel or a power cut), then `auditd` will be left permanently turned off.

There is some discussion about it in https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=729452.